# javascript parse time (minutes:seconds) from milliseconds

Tags: javascript, parsing, time

How to parse a given amount of milliseconds (e.g. `125230.41294642858`) into a time format like: `minutes:seconds`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
var ms = 125230.41294642858,
   min = 0|(ms/1000/60),
   sec = 0|(ms/1000) % 60;

alert(min + ':' + sec);
```

Comment: What is the `<<` operator doing?

Comment: @JaredPar - `Math.floor` via an implicit `int` cast  :)

Comment: @cwolves could you write the expanded syntax? Still too new to javascript to implicitly understand how that expands

Comment: @JaredPar - `<<` is a bitwise shift operator.  I'm shifting by 0, or doing "nothing".  Bitwise math, however, can only run on ints, not floats, so there is an internal cast to int inherit in that.  Functionally, it's identical to `Math.floor(ms/1000/60)` for all numbers < 2^31 (which I can safely assume this is), but much faster.

Comment: Nice one! What about `parseInt`?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - same thing functionally, parseInt is even slower though :)

Comment: Have any proof that the bitwise shift trick is the **most** efficient? Just wondering, as I rarely see it used even here in SO. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - go benchmark it, I can guarantee that it is simply because of the lack of a function call overhead.  I've never seen anyone else use it anywhere, but I started doing it years ago and it's habit.  It's also quicker to type.  But don't use `>>` as it's buggy out in one very-very specific case.

Comment: Cool! I might just start doing that as well. ;-) Why `>>` is buggy?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard - As I said, a very specific case: `({rnd:((Math.random())>>0)}).rnd` in `Safari 5.0 build 5533.16` breaks.  `<<` works.  They're the same thing so I use `<<` now :)

Comment: In my Vue application I had to add the <<0 operation to the seconds in order to get seconds without decimals, like for the minutes in the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
var num = Number(theTextValue);
var seconds = Math.floor(num / 1000);
var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
var seconds = seconds - (minutes * 60);
var format = minutes + ':' + seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Number.prototype.toTime = function(){
     var self = this/1000;
     var min = (self) << 0;
     var sec = (self*60) % 60;
     if (sec == 0) sec = '00';

     return min + ':' + sec
};


var ms = (new Number('250')).toTime();
console.log(ms);
=> '0:15'

var ms = (new Number('10500')).toTime();
console.log(ms);
=> '10:30'
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though moment.js does not provide such functionality, if you come here and you are already using moment.js, try this:

```
function getFormattedMs(ms) {
  var duration = moment.duration(ms);
  return moment.utc(duration.asMilliseconds()).format("mm:ss");
}
```

This workaround in moment was introduced in this [Issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1048).