# How do I show the javascript timer in my code in an html div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, countdown

I have a simple timer that times a test, which is working great

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var varTimerInMiliseconds = 3000;
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        document.getElementById("cntnt01moduleform_1").submit();
    }, varTimerInMiliseconds);
});
```

However, I also want to show the countdown to the student who is taking the test.  How can I pass the timer itself into a div with the ID of `id="testTimer"` and how can I convert the timer into minutes and seconds rather than milliseconds?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294302/converting-milliseconds-to-minutes-and-seconds-with-javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618355/the-simplest-possible-javascript-countdown-timer

Answer (score 1):

This code lets you to countdown from 5 to 1 and print into `testTimer` div.

```html
<div id="testTimer"></div>
```

JS code

```js
function Timer() {
  var counter = 10;
  var myTimer = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("testTimer").innerHTML = counter;
    counter--;
    if (counter < 0) {
      clearInterval(myTimer);
      document.getElementById("testTimer").style.color = "red";

      // do anything then time is up. ex: submit() function
      document.getElementById("cntnt01moduleform_1").submit();
    }
  }, 1000);
}
Timer();
```

As you can see there is no need for translating milliseconds to seconds by multiplying. You just do the update of seconds once in 1000 ms. [JS Feedle](https://jsfiddle.net/z75omns9/)

Comment: To add to this, You an find the breakdown of the time conversion of the countdown here [w3Schools How TO - JavaScript Countdown Timer](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp)

Comment: Great - thanks guys.  But how do I relate that to the existing code I have?  In the existing code, the two things that it is doing are..

1.  take the time in milliseconds (that's set elsewhere and called in, so I don't have a choice of it being seconds, it WILL be milliseconds.

2.  submit a form on countdown end.

I can't see how to use the code Giorgi showed as part of my code - i.e. do both the submit and the show and do it from milliseconds.

Comment: Hi @JohnSpartacusScotcher, thank you for updating your request. I updated also the code and commented on the place where you can add some other functions too. Also, you can countdown from 10 to 0 now, where the last `0` digit will become red too. If this is the code you needed to get, please consider accepting.

Comment: That's great, Giorgi - thank you very much.  I have it working now and counting down seconds.  (I converted the milliseconds I have into seconds outside of the script)>
The only last thing that would be great to understand how to do is how to show the timer in muites and seconds.  E.g. 90 seconds would countdown from 1:30 (minutes and seconds) rather than 90.
Thanks again.  :-)

Comment: I generally use division or mod functions. try this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294302/converting-milliseconds-to-minutes-and-seconds-with-javascript